# Kafka Consumer is Polling Messages Larger than 1.5 MB Despite MAX_PARTITION_FETCH_BYTES_CONFIG Setting

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have configured my Kafka consumer to limit the maximum message size to 1.5 MB by setting the MAX_PARTITION_FETCH_BYTES_CONFIG property. However, I noticed that the consumer is still polling messages larger than 1.5 MB from the partition. Here's my configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class ConsumerFactory {
    @Bean
    public Properties properties(KafkaConsumerProperties kafkaConsumerProperties) {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaConsumerProperties.getBootstrapServers());
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, kafkaConsumerProperties.getKeyDeserializer());
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, kafkaConsumerProperties.getValueDeserializer());
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, kafkaConsumerProperties.getGroupId());
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, kafkaConsumerProperties.getAutoOffsetReset());
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false");
        properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.MAX_PARTITION_FETCH_BYTES_CONFIG, "1572864");
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaConsumer kafkaConsumer(KafkaConsumerProperties kafkaConsumerProperties) {
        KafkaConsumer kafkaConsumer = new KafkaConsumer(properties(kafkaConsumerProperties));
        kafkaConsumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList(kafkaConsumerProperties.getTopics()));
        return kafkaConsumer;
    }
}
```

Despite setting MAX_PARTITION_FETCH_BYTES_CONFIG to 1.5 MB, the consumer is still polling messages larger than 2 MB from the partition. What could be the reason for this behavior? How can I ensure that the consumer adheres to the specified maximum message size limit?

Comment: The max.partition.fetch.bytes [documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs_max.partition.fetch.bytes) says *If the first record batch in the first non-empty partition of the fetch is larger than this limit, the batch will still be returned to ensure that the consumer can make progress.*